# JOGL2 - a problem with the project template

Tags: java, jogl

I decided to update JOGL2 to the newest version which is jogl-b434-2011-08-24 ([link](https://jogamp.org/deployment/autobuilds/master/)). Now I'm using an older version jogl-b391-2011-05-17. I noticed that after jogl-b419-2011-08-04 some changes were introduced, for example other jar nad dll files. I have a problem with my project template becasue the newest release doesn't contain glugen-rt.dll and it seems to be necessary here:

```
GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL3);
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Sven has made some changes to the jars. See the question I asked [here](http://forum.jogamp.org/JAR-inquisition-td3277996.html) regarding the new jars.